# Get data from report to program variable

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I use Crystal Reports in VS.

How can I copy the value of a specific report field into a variable in VB.NET which is manipulated in Report. Whenever A report opens, the value should be fetched from the report.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data of your report is came from your table am i right?

I suggest get the `value` from your `table` not the value from your `CR report`.

Comment: I Created procedures(3 procedures each for a subreport) as resource, inserted 3 subreports, declared shared variable to transfer data from sub report to main report and then manipulated those shared data with each other.
Yeah I know getting data from datatable/stored_procedure but If I do it like that then I have to apply all those formulas again..! Just finding an eazy way...! Because this isn't just 1 report I have to do in that way.!

By your answer, It seems that the thing I want is not possible, or there is no provision I guess.! So I shall not waste time in searching now.
Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do that. Apart from something ridiculous like taking screenshots or automating keypresses to manually copy-paste the value, I can't imagine how you'd pull it off.

But thankfully, any calculations a Crystal Report does, VB.NET can do the same and more! Just write some code to grab the same dataset/stored procedure and apply the same formulas in VB.

Comment: Ya, I am actually doing so now, calling data from procedures directly..
I learnt from this thing that CRREPORTS or any REPORTING SERVICE maybe just displays records and not return again...
Thanx anyways..!